# Reset Values in ArrayList Nested in While Loop

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

I wrote code to store the values of user-inputted dollar amounts. Whenever the program prompts the user, "would you like to input items - y/n?" the user can then put in values stored in an ArrayList.

The initial prompt is below. It seems to work as I am able to put in values with no visible errors.

```
    System.out.print("Would you like to input item/s - y/n: ");
    String response = textReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    // create while loop to restrict responses to single characters
    while ((!response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) && (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
    {
        System.out.print("Sorry - we need a y/n: ");
        response = textReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }
```

But when I go to put in values a second time, I notice the program doesn't clear out the values from my first entry. The code I wrote to prompt the user for another cluster of values is identical to the code I wrote for the initial prompt. I nested these second prompt in a while loop triggered by the user selecting "y" to the initial prompt.

```
while ((response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")))
    {
       System.out.print("Please enter an item price, or -1 to exit: $");
       double values = numberReader.nextDouble();
       while ((values > (-1)))
       {
           cartItems.add(values);
           System.out.print("Please enter another item price, or -1 to exit: $");
           values = numberReader.nextDouble(); 
       }
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("********** Here are your items **********");

       // I omitted the code here to make this more concise.

       // prompt the user to input a second round of values
       System.out.print("Would you like to input item/s - y/n: ");
       response = textReader.nextLine();
       System.out.println();
       // create while loop to restrict responses to single characters
       while ((!response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) && (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
       {
           System.out.print("Sorry - we need a y/n: ");
           response = textReader.nextLine();
           System.out.println();
       }
    }
```

My output is below. When I am prompted a second time, I select 'y' to add more items. However, my newly added item $3.00, gets added to the list from the first prompt. Is there anyway to refresh or erase the ArrayList so that it is brand new each time the user wants to input new values?
[image: My output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cartItems.clear();
```

put it at the end of the loop, after the results are printed to the console. 
It will refresh the list and remove all the elements within it.

Answer (score 4):

In no place you are resetting the `ArrayList`.

You can call `cartItems.clear()` when you are done with your processing and you are looping for a next round (at the bottom of the outter while).

```
       ...
       while ((!response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) && (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
       {
           System.out.print("Sorry - we need a y/n: ");
           response = textReader.nextLine();
           System.out.println();
       }
       cartItems.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create instance of list in the while loop

```
List<Double> cartList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

So now everytime user selects yes, the program enters in the while loop and then a new instance of list is created without any values. If you want to store the values in the previous list, write it to a persistence storage like file or database before creating a new instance of list.

Alternatively, you can also use

```
cartList.clear();
```

But, i don't recommend doing so.It can give you junk values and takes more amount of time. The clear method basically iterates over all the elements of list and does them null like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < cartList.size(); i++){
    cartList.get(i) = null;
}
```